# Pagination directive in angular-material

Tags: pagination, angular-material

Is there any pagination directive in angular-material to use with md-list?

These do work, but are not material design based.

- https://github.com/brantwills/Angular-Paging
- https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can mix these 2 projects but I would look to use bootstrap for angular, with a customization for material design;

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination

If it's not shaping enough for material design, here for the customization:

https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/

edit1: changed "materiel" to "material"

Comment: Bootstrap is very fine, so is this solution http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJXzpJ. 
But it would be nice to have a native angular-material directive.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've made a package [md-collection-pagination](https://github.com/jonatanklosko/md-collection-pagination) that is great for this use case.